# Reading a large *.txt file. Why didn't i get the output?

Tags: c, file-io

Hello all I'm trying to read a large txt file, word by word, then print each word out then continue on with the loop until EOF but I got no output after running this code.  I check everything, file name was correct, the file also in the same folder with my c file. Could anyone please explain what is going on? Thank you. Here is the txt file, and the code:

[.txt file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0aCz1udtGMuamZIZkhqdU9IZTg/view?usp=sharing)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    FILE *infile;
    char temp_1[25];
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    infile = fopen("LittleRegiment.txt", "r");

    if(infile != NULL) {
        while(fscanf(infile, "%s", temp_1) != EOF) {
            printf("%s ", temp_1);          
        }
    } else {
        printf("Couldn't open the file.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've failed to explain the problem with the code you've posted; *it didn't work* is not a useful description. In what way did it *not work*? Did it not open the file? Did it read too little data? Too much? The wrong data? If you want help, *clearly explain the problem* and *ask a specific question*.

Comment: You're getting no output at all?  Not even the error message?  Is there a particular reason you're calling `setvbuf` on `stdout`?  As a first pass, I'd suggest commenting out the `setvbuf` call and seeing if that changes anything.

Comment: The program you have posted does not allow me to reproduce your problem.  It compiles fine and produces what I assume is your expected output on the text file you have linked.  I have no other option than to vote for your question to be closed.  As a suggestion probably unrelated to your current problem: consider using a larger buffer.  25 is really small, there might be words that don't fit into.  And don't turn off input buffering.  It doesn't harm and makes your program run just that much faster.

Comment: Why did i get a vote down? I stated in the description that i get no output. I'm using eclipse and it is a good idea to use setvbuf.

Comment: You got a downvote because noone else can reproduce 'some problem' which you didnt even describe.

Comment: No, disabling buffering is a really bad idea.  If I comment out that line, your program runs *twice* as fast.

Comment: What weird is that if i put the new line character in, i get some output and missing alot of the content. Without the new line character, i get no output at all. Could this be esclipe or my pc that is causing problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try printing the reason for the error.

```
} else {
    //printf("Couldn't open the file.");
    perror("open file");                 // prototype in <stdio.h>
}
```